every orbit of this action has the same number of elements.

Let $G$ be a finite group acting transitively on a set $ X $, i.e.,
for every $x, y \in X $, there exists $g \in G$ such that $ gx = y $.
Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Consider the action of $H$ on
$X$. Prove that every orbit of this action has the same number of
elements.

I have prove a result that $\text{orb}(x)=X\quad\forall x\in X$. I don't know whether this can help to solve the main problem. I have no idea to continue though. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance

Hint: Show that given $x,y\in X$, their stabilizers in $G$ are conjugate to each other. (use the fact that $x,y$ belong to the same orbit)

@Mark I asked about the action of $H$ on $X$, not the action of $G$ on $X$

I know what you asked. I'm not solving the exercise for you, just giving a hint on how to start. Show their stabilizers in $G$ are conjugate, then use it to conclude that their stabilizers in $H$ are also isomorphic, and so have the same size.
